# how create session type list and add object ro this list session?

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-core

I want to create session that contains **list of object** and **adding new item to this list of session** in asp.net core?

Answer (score 0):

You could create extension methods for getting and setting values in session like so:

```
    public static class SessionExtensions
    {
         public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, 
                                   string key, T value)
         {
                session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
         }

         public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
         {
              var value = session.GetString(key);

               return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
         }
    }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
    Session.Set(SessionKey, list);
    var sessionList = Session.Get<List<object>>(SessionKey);
```